# SQL Server Protocols that Support NTLM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question, what are the four SQL server network configuration protocols that support NTLM authentication?

Comment: Is it a interview question?

Comment: Or a homework question?

Comment: homework...I can't figure out the answer; I've look online.

Answer (score 0):

With `NTLM` we mean `windows authentication` or `integrated security SSPI`. As far I know, in order to use SQL Server's integrated security, you must choose either `Named Pipes` or `Multi-Protocol with Named Pipes`.

You can see more here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266530%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I saw this page before and couldn't really see the answer to my question.